# Await useState update in React?

Tags: reactjs

In React can you await the update from `useState`?

EG here I would like `a` to be updated with the new text, and after that has completed then `b` gets set to true.

```
const [a, setA] = useState('');
const [b, setB] = useState(false);

const handleFocus = async (text: string) => {
  await setA(text);
  setB(true);
};
```

Comment: No, you can't. The state update function doesn't return a promise that can be awaited on. But due to the way react state updates are batch processed between render cycles, in the order they were enqueued, `a` will update with `text` *before* `b` updates to `true`, but from the component's perspective they occur "at the same time", i.e. they both are updated *for the next* render cycle. What is your *real* use case?

Comment: My real use case is that I need to change the value of a string, and also set an input to use this string as it's value. It's working fine but I thought it might be a bit tidier and also avoid a re-render.

Comment: Seems like one piece of state would suffice for that use-case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to use useEffect

```
const [a, setA] = useState('');
const [b, setB] = useState(false);

useEffect(() =>   setB(true), [a])

const handleFocus = async (text: string) => {
  await setA(text);
};
```